# stuck in questionnaire Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make COVID-19 questionnaire and I wrote some code.
What I want to make is questionnaire which has 5 questions. Answer is only yes:예 and no:아니오.
I'm going to say different things through 'yes or no' numbers. So I count 'yes or no' by 'yes = yes+1'
, 'no = no+1'.

The problem is after 'while True:'. if x=1 I would ask first question and after answered yes or no, by x=x+1, go to the next question and so on. However, after I run, It just stuck in first question and I have no idea to go next question.

I want to make code like this. https://stackoverrun.com/ko/q/13070335.

Thank you.

**questionnare.py**

```py
def yes_or_no(question):
    global yes
    global no
    yes = 0
    no = 0
    reply = str(input(question + ' (예/아니오): '))
    if reply == '예':
        yes = yes + 1
    elif reply == '아니오':
        no = no + 1
    else:
        return yes_or_no("(예/아니오)로만 대답하시오 (예/아니오) ")


x = 1
while True:
    if x == 1:
        if (yes_or_no('1. 현재 확진 판정을 받고 치료중에 있습니까?')):
            x = x + 1
    elif x == 2:
        if (yes_or_no('2. 현재 발열 또는 호흡기 증상(기침, 호흡곤란 등)이 있습니까?')):
            x = x + 1
    elif x == 3:
        if (yes_or_no('3. 14일 이내에 확진자와 접촉한 적이 있습니까?')):
            x = x + 1
    elif x == 4:
        if (yes_or_no('4. 14일 이내에 해외국가를 방문한 적이 있습니까?')):
            x = x + 1
    elif x == 5:
        if (yes_or_no('5. 14일 이내에 국내 집단 발생 지역 혹은 시설을 방문한 적이 있습니까?')):
            x = x + 1
    else:
        break

if yes == 1 :
    print('능동감시 대상자입니다.')
elif yes>no :
    print('의심환자입니다.')
else:
    print('건강관리에 유의하세요.')
```

Comment: Why the `x` variable? Why not just loop on the questions with `for`? Anyway your function can only return `None` so the `if` is never executed

Comment: You also need to indent the section below `while`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `yes_or_no` function does not return in some cases. Try the following

```py
def yes_or_no(question):
    global yes
    global no
    yes = 0
    no = 0
    reply = str(input(question + ' (예/아니오): '))
    if reply == 'y':
        yes = yes + 1
        return True
    elif reply == 'n':
        no = no + 1
        return True
    else:
        return yes_or_no("(예/아니오)로만 대답하시오 (예/아니오) ")
```